# NaN в некоторых браузерах

Tags: php, javascript, html

Доброго дня! Такой код почему-то дает NaN в Safari. Как исправить?

```
function returnRoubles(roubles)
{
    if(roubles % 10 == 1 && (roubles == 1 || roubles > 20)) return "рубль";
    else if((roubles % 10 == 2 || roubles % 10 == 3 || roubles % 10 == 4) && (roubles < 10 || roubles > 20)) return "рубля";
    else return "рублей";
}
function returnCop(roubles)
{
    if((roubles % 10 == 1) && (roubles == 1 || roubles > 20)) return "копейку";
    else if((roubles % 10 == 2 || roubles % 10 == 3 || roubles % 10 == 4) && (roubles < 10 || roubles > 20)) return "копейки";
    else return "копеек";
}
function setText() {
    if(document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML == "Ты накопил уже 0 рублей 0 копеек")
    {
        var curDate = new Date('<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>');
        var startDate  = new Date('<?php echo $main['startDate']; ?>');
        money = Math.floor(((curDate-startDate)*<?php echo $main['money']; ?>)/(864000));
    }
    else money = money + 1; 
    console.log("money: "+money);
    document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML = "Ты накопил уже <br>"+Math.floor(money/100)+" "+returnRoubles(Math.floor(money/100))+" "+money%100+" "+returnCop(money%100);
    showMoney(money);
}
setText();
console.log("interval: "+<?php echo round(864000/$main['money']); ?>);
setInterval(setText,<?php echo round(864000/$main['money']); ?>);
```

На экран: **Ты накопил уже NaN рублей NaN копеек**

```
function setText() {
    if(document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML == "Ты накопил уже 0 рублей 0 копеек")
    {
        var curDate = new Date('2017-08-01 16:30:51');
        var startDate  = new Date('2017-08-01 16:24:40');
        money = Math.floor(((curDate-startDate)*50)/(864000));
    }
    else money = money + 1; 
    console.log("money: "+money);
    document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML = "Ты накопил уже <br>"+Math.floor(money/100)+" "+returnRoubles(Math.floor(money/100))+" "+money%100+" "+returnCop(money%100);
    showMoney(money);
}
setText();
console.log("interval: "+17280);
setInterval(setText,17280);
```

html:

```
<h1 class='ontimer' id='cnt'>Ты накопил уже 0 рублей 0 копеек</h1>
```

Comment: А что у вас в JS PHP делает? :)

Comment: И лучше сразу приучатся придерживаться какого-нибудь стандарта оформления кода, например, [JavaScript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript).

Comment: @AlexanderBragin Нужно переменную из php в код вставить, чтобы верно зациклить

Comment: Тогла пока вопрос с JS. Вставьте, пожалуйтса, тогда пример кода JS уже сгенерированный (без PHP). Добавлю: тот, в котором возникает ошибка.

Comment: @AlexanderBragin Добавил.

Comment: как элемент с id="cnt" выглядит сначала? Добавьте тоже в вопрос. У вас проверка идет `if(document.getElementById("cnt").innerHTML == "Ты накопил уже 0 рублей 0 копеек")` и money нигде не объявляется, если только выше в коде где-нибудь нет объявления? Пока с этим надо разобраться...

Comment: @AlexanderBragin Не понимаю, почему это так важно, но добавил. Как я и говорил, не работает только в Safari, код абсолютно рабочий в Chrome, Firefox, дефолтном браузере Android.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63160/discussion-between-alexander-bragin-and-atcliff).

Comment: я вам в чате отвечаю, удобно?

Comment: Возможно движок JS в Safari неявно не может перевести new Date() в арифметических операциях в timestamp. Попробуйте сделать это явно: `var curDate = new Date('2017-08-01 16:30:51').getTime();` и `var startDate  = new Date('2017-08-01 16:24:40').getTime();`

Comment: да, вы правы. В текущей ситуации остальной код лишний. С Safari просто раньше не работал и не тестировал в нем. Но теперь для меня примером будет, что тоже важно. Ответил ниже. Пробуйте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Проблема**

Проблема специфична для Internet Explorer и Safari.

```js
var date = new Date("2011-02-07");  
console.log(date);
```

или

```js
var date = new Date("2011-02-07T11:05:00");  
console.log(date);
```

> Если вы выполнили приведенные выше фрагменты кода в разных браузерах,
>   вы увидите, что в IE вы получите «NaN», а в Safari вы получите
>   «Invalid Date». Однако Firefox, Chrome и Opera выводят
>   правильную дату.

**Решение**

> Проблема заключается в том, что вы передаете требуемую дату объекту
>   Date (). По какой-то причине и не спрашивайте меня, почему два
>   вышеупомянутых браузера на удивление не поддерживают формат даты
>   «yyyy-mm-dd» и поэтому терпят неудачу. Мне не удалось составить
>   окончательный список поддерживаемых форматов дат, однако я могу
>   сказать, что следующие форматы определенно поддерживаются во всех
>   браузерах и будут советовать придерживаться одного из них, чтобы
>   избежать ошибок:

**Нужно заменить формат дат на следующий.**

```js
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07); // yyyy, mm-1, dd
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07, 11, 05, 00); // yyyy, mm-1, dd, hh, mm, ss
var d = new Date("02/07/2011"); // "mm/dd/yyyy"
var d = new Date("02/07/2011 11:05:00"); // "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
var d = new Date(1297076700000); // milliseconds
var d = new Date("Mon Feb 07 2011 11:05:00 GMT"); // ""Day Mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT/UTC
```

Полностью текст в оригинале: [JavaScript new Date() Returning NaN in IE or Invalid Date in Safari](http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari/)

Comment: Cпасибо, что повозились со мной)

Comment: @atcliff всегда, пожалуйста. В датами как оказалось, да и вообще с JavaScript очень внимательно надо быть — фиг знает как он себя в браузерах поведет. Постоянно нужно проверять и тестировать)

Answer (score 0):

NaN - Not a Number
Вы пытаетесь / получаете не число и пытаетесь использовать его как число.
Попробуйте типизировать получаемые значения функцией parseInt.
Больше всего вызывает подозрение `$main['money']` возможно вы строковое значение используете в математических функциях.

Comment: Во всех браузерах, кроме Safari все выглядит нормально. Да и в консоли видно, что там строго цифры.

Comment: @AtCliff_, Safari сейчас это как IE6 недавно :)

Comment: @Visman Вот и как после этого для iPhone корректно вывести?))